Can you change the PSD plot x-axis (frequency) range in MANTA?
I am using MANTA to create PSD plots, is it possible to change the x-axis range (frequency range)? The sample rate used was 96 kHz, and the PSD output has a frequency range of 0-48 kHz, is it possible to produce a PSD plot for a specified frequency range in MANTA?

I'm not familiar enough with MANTA to be able to say whether such a feature is included within that software or not.
However, it is a common practice to down sample (AKA decimate) audio if one is only interested in lower frequency sounds. There's even a post in this very stack exchange that provides a number of different ways and software packages for down sampling including application of anti-aliasing filter to prevent distortion. It sounds like MANTA will by default produce PSD at the Nyquist rate (half the sample rate). So if you wanted PSD with a frequency range of 0-10 kHz you could resample at a rate of 20 - 24 kHz (with the higher rate providing a buffer around the anti-aliasing filter to preserve energy around 10 kHz if that's important).
Resampling lots of audio can take a long amount of time depending on the hardware and software used (e.g. many hours/days to resample years of audio). But subsequent analysis on the lower sample rate recordings will usually complete faster, and this can be very beneficial if you're exploring methods and running multiple analyses over the whole dataset.
